# #import <vector> #import <algorithm> #define - Swift equivalents

Tags: objective-c, swift

This translation is quite difficult for me. I've never dealt with #define statements and in the processValue() function they look like nested arrays or something but I have idea how to deal with them.  What about `#import <vector>    #import <algorithm>`? Can I ignore those if I already have UIKit?

I have decided to put all the code for the two Obj-C custom classes in the single ViewController.swift file. I recognize common methods and properties but other than that I'm lost since this involves a lot of math methods.

Could someone PLEASE translate this mess to Swift for me?

```
//Detector.h     

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>    
#define MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE 20
#define AVERAGE_SIZE 20
#define INVALID_DETECT_PERIOD -1

@interface Detector : NSObject {  
float upVals[AVERAGE_SIZE];
float downVals[AVERAGE_SIZE];
int upValIndex;
int downValIndex;

float lastVal;
float periodStart;
double periods[MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE];
double periodTimes[MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE];

int periodIndex;
bool started;
float freq;
float average;

bool wasDown;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) float periodStart; 


-(float) addNewValue:(float) newVal atTime:(double) time; 
-(float) getAverage; 
-(void) reset; 
@end


//Detector.m

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "Detector.h"
#import <vector>
#import <algorithm>

#define MAX_PERIOD 1.5
#define MIN_PERIOD 0.1
#define INVALID_ENTRY -100

@implementation Detector

@synthesize periodStart;


- (id) init
{
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
// set everything to invalid
[self reset];
}
return self;
}

-(void) reset {
for(int i=0; i<MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE; i++) {
    periods[i]=INVALID_ENTRY;
}
for(int i=0; i<AVERAGE_SIZE; i++) {
    upVals[i]=INVALID_ENTRY;
    downVals[i]=INVALID_ENTRY;
}   
  freq=0.5;
  periodIndex=0;
  downValIndex=0;
  upValIndex=0;
}

-(float) addNewValue:(float) newVal atTime:(double) time {
// we keep track of the number of values above and below zero
if(newVal>0) {
    upVals[upValIndex]=newVal;
    upValIndex++;
    if(upValIndex>=AVERAGE_SIZE) {
        upValIndex=0;
    }
}
if(newVal<0) {
    downVals[downValIndex]=-newVal;
    downValIndex++;
    if(downValIndex>=AVERAGE_SIZE) {
        downValIndex=0;
    }       
}
// work out the average value above zero
float count=0;
float total=0;
for(int i=0; i<AVERAGE_SIZE; i++) {
    if(upVals[i]!=INVALID_ENTRY) {
        count++;
        total+=upVals[i];
    }
}
float averageUp=total/count;
// and the average value below zero
count=0;
total=0;
for(int i=0; i<AVERAGE_SIZE; i++) {
    if(downVals[i]!=INVALID_ENTRY) {
        count++;
        total+=downVals[i];
    }
}
float averageDown=total/count;

// is the new value a down value?
if(newVal<-0.5*averageDown) {
    wasDown=true;
}

// is the new value an up value and were we previously in the down state?
if(newVal>=0.5*averageUp && wasDown) {
    wasDown=false;
// work out the difference between now and the last time this happenned
    if(time-periodStart<MAX_PERIOD && time-periodStart>MIN_PERIOD) {
        periods[periodIndex]=time-periodStart;
        periodTimes[periodIndex]=time;
        periodIndex++;
        if(periodIndex>=MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE) {
            periodIndex=0;
        }
    }
// track when the transition happened
    periodStart=time;
} 
// return up or down
if(newVal<-0.5*averageDown) {
    return -1;
} else if(newVal>0.5*averageUp) {
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}

-(float) getAverage {
double time=CACurrentMediaTime();
double total=0;
double count=0;
for(int i=0; i<MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE; i++) {
// only use upto 10 seconds worth of data
    if(periods[i]!=INVALID_ENTRY  && time-periodTimes[i]<10) {
        count++;
        total+=periods[i];
    }
}
// do we have enough values?
if(count>2) {
    return total/count;
}
return INVALID_DETECT_PERIOD;
}

@end


//Filter.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define NZEROS 10
#define NPOLES 10

@interface Filter : NSObject {    
float xv[NZEROS+1], yv[NPOLES+1];  
}

-(float) processValue:(float) value;  

@end


//Filter.m

#import "Filter.h"

#define GAIN    1.894427025e+01


@implementation Filter

-(float) processValue:(float) value {   // the function processValue that was declared in .h 
xv[0] = xv[1]; xv[1] = xv[2]; xv[2] = xv[3]; xv[3] = xv[4]; xv[4] = xv[5]; xv[5] = xv[6]; xv[6] = xv[7]; xv[7] = xv[8]; xv[8] = xv[9]; xv[9] = xv[10]; 
xv[10] = value / GAIN;
yv[0] = yv[1]; yv[1] = yv[2]; yv[2] = yv[3]; yv[3] = yv[4]; yv[4] = yv[5]; yv[5] = yv[6]; yv[6] = yv[7]; yv[7] = yv[8]; yv[8] = yv[9]; yv[9] = yv[10]; 
yv[10] =   (xv[10] - xv[0]) + 5 * (xv[2] - xv[8]) + 10 * (xv[6] - xv[4])
+ ( -0.0000000000 * yv[0]) + (  0.0357796363 * yv[1])
+ ( -0.1476158522 * yv[2]) + (  0.3992561394 * yv[3])
+ ( -1.1743136181 * yv[4]) + (  2.4692165842 * yv[5])
+ ( -3.3820859632 * yv[6]) + (  3.9628972812 * yv[7])
+ ( -4.3832594900 * yv[8]) + (  3.2101976096 * yv[9]);
return yv[10];
}

@end
```

// Attempt at Swift Translation

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import AVFoundation


#define GAIN    1.894427025e+01
#define MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE 20
#define AVERAGE_SIZE 20
#define INVALID_DETECT_PERIOD -1

class ViewController: UIViewController {

// Set up Camera
let session = AVCaptureSession()
// If we find a device we'll store it here for later use
var camera : AVCaptureDevice?


var detector = Detector.self
var filter = Filter.self


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}

class Filter: NSObject {

var xv:Float
var yv:Float

func processValue(value: Float) -> Float {
    xv[0] = xv[1]; xv[1] = xv[2]; xv[2] = xv[3]; xv[3] = xv[4]; xv[4] = xv[5]; xv[5] = xv[6]; xv[6] = xv[7]; xv[7] = xv[8]; xv[8] = xv[9]; xv[9] = xv[10]; xv[10] = value / GAIN;
    yv[0] = yv[1]; yv[1] = yv[2]; yv[2] = yv[3]; yv[3] = yv[4]; yv[4] = yv[5]; yv[5] = yv[6]; yv[6] = yv[7]; yv[7] = yv[8]; yv[8] = yv[9]; yv[9] = yv[10];
    yv[10] =   (xv[10] - xv[0]) + 5 * (xv[2] - xv[8]) + 10 * (xv[6] - xv[4])
    + ( -0.0000000000 * yv[0]) + (  0.0357796363 * yv[1])
    + ( -0.1476158522 * yv[2]) + (  0.3992561394 * yv[3])
    + ( -1.1743136181 * yv[4]) + (  2.4692165842 * yv[5])
    + ( -3.3820859632 * yv[6]) + (  3.9628972812 * yv[7])
    + ( -4.3832594900 * yv[8]) + (  3.2101976096 * yv[9]);
    return yv[10];
}

}

class Detector: NSObject {

var upVals: Float
var downVals: Float
var upValIndex: Int
var downValIndex: Int
var lastVal: Float
var periodStart: Float
var periods: Double
var periodTimes: Double
var periodIndex: Int
var started: Bool
var freq: Float
var average: Float
var wasDown: Bool


func reset() {
    for var i=0; i < MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE; i++ {
        periods[i]=INVALID_ENTRY
    }
    for var i=0; i<AVERAGE_SIZE; i++ {
        upVals[i]=INVALID_ENTRY
        downVals[i]=INVALID_ENTRY
    }
    freq=0.5;
    periodIndex=0;
    downValIndex=0;
    upValIndex=0;
}

func addNewValue(newVal:Float, atTime:Double) -> Float {     // the function addNewValue that was declared in .h
// we keep track of the number of values above and below zero
if newVal > 0 {
upVals[upValIndex] = newVal
upValIndex++
if(upValIndex>=AVERAGE_SIZE) {
upValIndex = 0
}
}
if newVal < 0 {
downVals[downValIndex] =- newVal
downValIndex++
if downValIndex >= AVERAGE_SIZE {
downValIndex = 0
}
}
// work out the average value above zero
var count: Float
var total: Float
for var i=0; i < AVERAGE_SIZE; i++) {
if upVals[i]!=INVALID_ENTRY {
count++
total+=upVals[i]
}
}
var averageUp = total/count
// and the average value below zero
count=0;
total=0;
for var i=0; i < AVERAGE_SIZE; i++ {
if downVals[i]!=INVALID_ENTRY {
count++
total+=downVals[i]
}
}
var averageDown = total/count

// is the new value a down value?
if newVal < (-0.5*averageDown) {
wasDown = true
}

// is the new value an up value and were we previously in the down state?
if newVal >= (0.5*averageUp) && (wasDown) {
wasDown = false
// work out the difference between now and the last time this happenned
if time-periodStart < MAX_PERIOD && time-periodStart > MIN_PERIOD {
periods[periodIndex]=time-periodStart
periodTimes[periodIndex]=time
periodIndex++
if periodIndex >= MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE {
            periodIndex = 0
}
}
// track when the transition happened
periodStart = time
}
// return up or down
if newVal < (-0.5*averageDown) {
return -1
} else if newVal > (0.5*averageUp) {
return 1
}
return 0
}




}
```

Comment: First, avoid all those exclamation marks. They're useless and horrible. Second, an array declaration in Swift is `var upVals: [Float]` and you don't need to declare their size upfront like in C.

Comment: Ok I went through and fixed a lot of it. 20 errors remaining. Mostly due to the use of `MAX_PERIODS_TO_STORE`, `INVALID_ENTRY` ,  `AVERAGE_SIZE` in the Obj-C for loops and the declaration of variables with `upVals[upValIndex] = newVal` syntax. Also I wasn't quite sure with the translation of `-(float) addNewValue:(float) newVal atTime:(double) time {}`. Is it `func addNewValue(newVal:Float, atTime:Double) -> Float {}`?

Comment: I have since found out that #define statements are C macros. So how on earth do I deal with them since Swift doesn't have them? Someone said that you can use constants i.e. let defaultHeight = 100. But how do I know what is a constant an if it isn't a constant how would I construct? Also I edited all. Filter.h/.h and detector.h/.m plus Swift. The processValue() function is very confusing with all the square brackets. Are those nested arrays?

Comment: I did `class Filter: NSObject {
    
    var xv:Float
    var yv:Float
    
    func processValue(value: Float) -> Float {
        
        let gain = 1.894427025e+01` and I also did `func reset() {
        
        let maxPeriodsToStore = 20
        let averageSize = 20
        
        for var i=0; i < maxPeriodsToStore; i++ {
            periods[i]=INVALID_ENTRY
        }
        for var i=0; i < averageSize; i++ {
            upVals[i] = INVALID_ENTRY
            downVals[i] = INVALID_ENTRY
        }
`.  No errors.

Comment: There is also no need to inherit from `NSObject` in Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#define`s in C/C++/Obj-C were used to create global constants. In Swift they can be easily translated in the following way:

```
let GAIN = 1.894427025e+01
let AVERAGE_SIZE = 20
let INVALID_DETECT_PERIOD = -1
```

Of course, they don't have to be declared on global scope (or module scope in Swift). If you don't want to share them between classes or modules, declaring them inside a class or even inside a method/function is better. Always try to limit the scope as much as possible.

Macros are not actually a part of C/C++/Obj-C, the macro gets replaced with its value during preprocessing. There are better ways to define global constants in C/C++/Obj-C using `const` but the macros are still widely used. Since macros are not part of the language itself, you can put them anywhere in the file (before first use), they are not limited by scopes.

The headers `<vector>` and `<algorithm>` are not included in `UIKit`, however, I am pretty sure you don't need them because I don't see any functions from those headers used in your code. `<vector>` is related to C++ container type `vector` (a list of elements). `<algorithms>` is related to operations on containers. I don't think Swift would operate well with templated C++ types anyway.

The initialization of arrays is different in Swift and C. In C the arrays are "stupid". You have first declare the array, giving it a size and then assign a value to every element.

```
float xv[NZEROS+1]
```

In swift you can initialize the array directly with values.

```
var xv = [Float](count: NZEROS + 1, repeatedValue: 0)
```

Comment: Yeah thanks. I posted that prior. I declared them as constants within the functions they apply to and no errors.  In the C version Detector.m it has `periods[i]=INVALID_ENTRY` in the reset(). How do I deal with that?

Comment: @Edward Haven't seen your comment. I have added a more detailed explanation though.

Comment: Thanks Sulthan. My comment is above your answer. It says "I did class `Filter: NSObject { var xv:Float var yv:Float func processValue(value: Float) -> Float { let gain = 1.894427025e+01`"

Comment: @Edward You can answer your own question too if you have already found a solution...

Comment: I haven't found a solution to this entire translation yet. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Edward What part is giving you problems? This question is a big broad.

Comment: There is a lot of confusing syntax like `@interface Filter : NSObject {    
 float xv[NZEROS+1], yv[NPOLES+1];  
}`.   Can I do it like this: `class Filter {
    
     xv[NZEROS+1], yv[NPOLES+1];
    
    let NZEROS = 10
    let NPOLES = 10
    
    var xv:Float
    var yv:Float`?

Comment: @Edward Added a part about array declaration/initialization

Comment: Also in ViewController.m (I didn't post it) has a function called `// r,g,b values are from 0 to 1 // h = [0,360], s = [0,1], v = [0,1]
// if s == 0, then h = -1 (undefined)
void RGBtoHSV( float r, float g, float b, float *h, float *s, float *v ) {}`   so I might need `<vector>` and `<algorithm>` right?

Comment: I have an issue with "#defines were used to create global constants". Macros != constants.

Comment: @LeoNatan Technically true but in practice macros were (and still are) used to define constants, in the meaning of a value that can't change.

Comment: @Edward Just declare `gain` as `Float`, using `let gain: Float = ...` or add explicit casts `= Float(Double(value) / gain)`

Comment: But I already did in that screenshot. `let gain  = 1.894427025e+01`. You have to give me a completed example because I'm still new to Swift and Obj-C. I've completed a Swift curriculum and only half way through my C curriculum. You've given me a lot of help so I just marked you answer as correct  :)  If you could keep adding to your answer that would be fantastic. Btw, I've gone from 80 errors to 16 today so this can happen!

Comment: @Edward If you just declare `gain` as you did, it will become a `Double` not a `Float`, that's why you have to say explicitly it's a `Float`. C would cast from Float to Double and viceversa by itself but Swift doesn't so you have to do the operations on the same type (`Float` and `Float`). If one of the types is `Double`, you have to add casts.

Comment: DONE  `let NZEROS = 10
let NPOLES = 10

class Filter {
    
    var xv = [Float](count: NZEROS + 1, repeatedValue: 0)
    var yv = [Float](count: NPOLES + 1, repeatedValue: 0)
    
    func processValue(value: Float) -> Float {
        
        let gain: Float = 1.894427025e+01`

Comment: What is this Objective-C  `=-newValue` syntax? That's not a binary operator  so what is it? The statements is this `if(newVal<0) {
  downVals[downValIndex]=-newVal;
  downValIndex++;
  if(downValIndex>=AVERAGE_SIZE) {
   downValIndex=0;
  }  `     Check out the screenshot. Line 57.  Error: Operator is not a known operator. In Objective-C there's no error.  http://i.imgur.com/ld6Tre0.png  ----  I'm also getting subscript errors. http://i.imgur.com/0GvKeOF.png